# Why does my deleteMessage function not work?

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I am using Postman to simulate deleting some data from my `JSON` database when I send a `DELETE` request via `http://localhost:3001/delete/1` in my `backend/lib/routes.js`

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const messageApp = require('./controller.js');
const router = Router();
...
router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  await messageApp
    .deleteMessage(req.params.id)
    .then((messages) => {
      res.json(messages);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json(err));
});
export default router;
```

During my `DELETE` request, `req.params.id === 1`, which carries this `1` over to the `deleteMessage(id)` function in my `backend/lib/controller.js`

```
import MessageModel from './model';
let messageApp = new MessageModel(`/\///json/\//testMessages.json`);
...
function deleteMessage(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = messageApp.delete(id);
    if (result !== 'Message not found in database') {
      resolve(result);
    } else {
      reject(result);
    }
  });
}
module.exports = {
  ...
  deleteMessage,
};
```

`messageApp` is from my `backend/lib/model.js` and the `1` gets accepted by the `delete(id)` function

```
...
class MessageApp {
  constructor(filepath) {
    this.filepath = filepath;
    this.messages = filepath ? this.readFromJson() : [];
  }
  ...
  delete(id) {
    let index = this.messages.findIndex((message) => message.id === id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.messages = this.messages.filter((message) => message.id !== id);
      this.writeToJson();
      return this.messages;
    } else {
      return 'Message not found in database';
    }
  }

  readFromJson() {
    return JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(
        __dirname + path.normalize(this.filepath),
        'utf8',
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      )
    );
  }
  writeToJson() {
    if (this.filepath) {
      const jsonItem = JSON.stringify(this.messages);
      fs.writeFileSync(
        __dirname + path.normalize(this.filepath),
        jsonItem,
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
export default MessageApp;
```

Within the `delete(id)` function, every time, `this.messages` is read, `this.messages` = the argument within

```
let messageApp = new MessageModel(`/\///json/\//testMessages.json`);
```

Then `this.readFromJson()` is called, reading the contents of my `backend/lib/json/testMessages.json` database which contains

```
[{"content":"hi world","date":"2020-11-22T05:04:43.572Z","id":1}]
```

When I try sending a `DELETE` request via Postman in `http://localhost:3001/delete/1` , I expected to return this array of `JSON`, why am I returning `"Message not found in database"`?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/mern-app)

Comment: do a console.log('index',index) in your delete function, then you will see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting the wrong response because your comparing a string to a number. When "finding" the index it's return is `-1` because you are using the equivalence operator `===`. You just need to type cast the string to a number when grabbing the param.

```
let id = Number(req.params.id);
await messageApp
.deleteMessage(id)
.then((messages) => {
  res.json(messages);
})
.catch((err) => res.status(404).json(err));
```

once you do this it will return an empty array. **NOTE** it's good practice to validate params or query in a request. Bare this in-mind.